# Increasing WiFi rss scan rate in android

Tags: android, rss, wifi

I am trying to increase the rate of WiFi signal strength scanning. I use getRssi() but it can provide an updated signal strength every 2 seconds. Is there anyway to increase its rate ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From tests in Android 4.4 and 5.0 the interval between sequential WiFi scans seems to be less than a second. If that is the case, then you can use a count down timer to get wifi results as often as you want after you first determine your minimum time needed between each scan. Beware that may be differs from device to device so keep a meaningful time window. You can take a look at my demo for RF measurements using Android device, here:

https://github.com/panosvas/Measurements

I have also created a Server for storing these measurements as well as a remote trigger app using UDP packets where you can find here:

https://github.com/panosvas/IndoorPositioningServer